# Modify ribbon and emails view with mail app for Outlook

Tags: office-2013, office365-apps

I have two question:

1. Is it possible to insert custom buttons to the Outlook rich client/OWA ribbon using mail app or some other type of app for Office?
2. Is it possible to create custom e-mail views with additional columns and filters using mail app or some other type of app for Office?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not currently insert items in to the ribbon or create views and filters using office apps based on the API surface that is currently available.  The documentation at http://dev.office.com lists some samples for what you can do and the API space for mail apps specifically is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp161015.aspx#olowacon15_FundJSAPI).  That link also discusses contextual activation and a lot of info on what mail apps can do.